# Randomized response vs Output Perturbation

Tags: randomized-algorithms

what are the difference between Randomized response and output perturbation?

The only one I can think of is that Randomized Response's output is not always perturbated while in the other case it is.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Privacy on databases